# node-red-node-mysql full disk

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, node-red

I have a project with node-red and I am using node-red-node-mysql to manipulate data inside my Mysql Workbench.
I do the next actions: insert data, update data, query for some rows to display them on the screen.
When I start my project, the PC's disk is almost instantly at 99% by "mysql.exe"

Below you can see 2 of my flows that use the connection to my database.

[image]
[image]

If I stop my server, my Disk usage goes to 1%

I refer to Disk like in the image below
[image]

Could somebody help me out here with a suggestion?
Could it be something from the configuration of mysql?
P.S: I am jut a n00b trying to understand node-red and use it :)

Comment: Very nice diagram, but how is that helping describe this situation

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to programming?

Comment: _Small Terminology Point_ MySQL Workbench is a tool, not a database. MySQL is the database

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "PC's disk is almost instantly at 99%"? Do you mean it's read/write io bound or do you mean that it's actually full?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Node-RED is a flow based low code environment, the "diagram" is the program that is running, but it's not really useful to the actual question.

Comment: I edited my post with a print screen of what I meant by "Disk". It seems it takes like 4-5 seconds to do a simple query of selecting last record from a table.

Comment: Sounds like you need to look at how to gather mysql performance metrics and then how to use then to tune the db along with possibly challenging your schema design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated a bit the pc and decided to use another station.
After moving everything to another server, it works just fine. I think that the problem came after a windows update — my HDD runs slower, much slower.